# "Yesterday I watched a film" "Yesterday, I saw a film.'

Tags: meaning-in-context

Aren't they both considered correct? "Yesterday I watched a film" "Yesterday, I saw a film.'

Comment: Are you seeing movies in your free time. Is this sentence ryt as past tence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are both correct and in both cases the comma is optional. To watch something is to intentionally pay attention to it for some period of time. So certainly you "watch" a movie. To have seen something just means that the thing was within your visual field. "Seeing" something can be instantaneous and unintentional. You "see" the flash of a camera, but you don't "watch" it. In the case of "seeing" or "watching" a film, I don't think either of the words is preferred over the other.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, let me first paraphrase Swan's "Practical English Usage" (#368):

- *See* is used when to talk about visual impressions coming to our eyes; it's not always deliberate, might be accidental; seeing could happen without you thinking about it, or even without you realising that you've done it
- *Look (at)* suggests intention or concentration
- *Watch* suggests intention or concentration while looking at something that is happening, changing, moving, developing.
- While we say *"watch TV"*, we usually use *"see"* with public performances of plays and films

---

That being said:
- you can *watch TV*, but you can't *see TV* (unless in the sense of, "I saw a nice TV in the store the other day" - in which case you can't really *watch* it).

- you can both *watch* and *see* movies. In some cases, the *watch* version may imply more of a deliberate looking than the *see* version:

  > I saw 'Gone with the Wind' yesterday.
  >
  > I watched 'Gone with the Wind' yesterday.
- however, note that if you're talking about movies you have seen at some point in the past (ie., you have watched them, and now you know what they're about), then "I've seen 'Gone with the Wind'" would seem a bit more natural to me than "I've watched 'Gone with the Wind'".
- finally, if you're talking about watching a film/movie N times, you can say both "I've seen 'Gone with the Wind' 5 times" and "I've watched 'Gone with the Wind' 5 times" (and the same goes for sentences of the type "I watched/saw X for the Nth time today"), and which version you choose here is up to you.

Comment: The corollary to your final point is that if you were to say *"I XXXX'ed 'Gone with the Wind' **for the third time** yesterday"*, you'd be more likely to use ***watched*** than ***saw*** (but both are perfectly valid, and it would be fatuous to suggest either is "more correct" than the other).

Comment: Yes, I was planning on adding that comment, but then forgot :) Thanks for adding it. Will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Was the question _really_ about the comma (or lack thereof), or **see** vs. **watch**?

Comment: @PhilPerry Did you meant to post this comment on Jolene's answer? :)

Comment: No, though it was triggered by her answer. Your answer was excellent, but hers got me to wondering just what was being asked.

Comment: @PhilPerry Ahh, now I understand :) It's a fair question. I'm going to assume it was the see vs watch since the OP accepted my answer, but yes - it wasn't 100% clear what was being asked :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it depends on context.  It comes back to the question of "intent" or "concentration".

So, I could say "I *went* to see a play".  Intent (and presumably contration) are implied.

"I *watched* a movie."  Could have been from the comfort of my own home, the use of the word watched implies intent and concentration.  Had I gone to the cinema, I could have easily said "I *went* to see a movie".